# Unexpected indent and other errors

Tags: python

```
class Pacco:
    STATES = ('Il pacco e` stato ordinato ma non ancora spedito',
              'Il pacco e` stato spedito ma non ancora ricevuto',
              'Il pacco e` stato ricevuto')
    indice = 0
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.state = Pacco.STATES[0]
        self._succ = Pacco.STATES[1]
        self._prec = None

    def next(self):
        print(self.state)

    @property
    def state(self):
        Pacco.indice += 1
        self.state = Pacco.STATES[Pacco.indice]
        self._succ = Pacco.STATES[Pacco.indice+1]
        self._prec = Pacco.STATES[Pacco.indice-1]
```

At `indice = 0` it gives me the error `Unexpected indent` and at the line `Pacco.indice += 1` it gives me the error

```
Unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

And at the next 3 lines it gives the errors

```
Unresolved reference 'self'...
```

Can someone tell me why?

Comment: Are you learning Python 2? I'd recommend learning Python 3 instead if possible, since 2 hit EOL at the start of 2020, and 3 is much better anyway. BTW, welcome to SO! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've mixed tabs and spaces. Convert all the tabs to spaces ([per PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces)), and the syntax works fine.

Note: The Stack Overflow formatter converts tabs to four spaces, so you can't see it in the post, but you can if you check the [source](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/03e1317e-5bfb-46eb-b448-eb1bc03d3ab8/view-source).

Comment: i replaced the tabs with the spaces and it solved the problem, big thank you

Answer (score 0):

First of all, keep all of your predefined variables inside your `__init__` function. Second, the `self.state` variable needs to be `self._state` because there is a function with the same name. Third, refer to [@wjandrea's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63749654/4518341) for his advice on tabs and space formatting. The code should be like this:

```
class Pacco:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.STATES = ('Il pacco e` stato ordinato ma non ancora spedito',
                       'Il pacco e` stato spedito ma non ancora ricevuto',
                       'Il pacco e` stato ricevuto')
        self.indice = 0
        self._state = self.STATES[0]
        self._succ = self.STATES[1]
        self._prec = None

    def next(self):
        print(self.state)

    @property
    def state(self):
        self.indice += 1
        self._state = self.STATES[self.indice]
        self._succ = self.STATES[self.indice+1]
        self._prec = self.STATES[self.indice-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `autopep8`

`pip install autopep8`

now type `autopep8 <yourfile.py>` in the terminal and enter

see that code will now be formatted in the right way